# Rewriting a JSON string - grouping keys by value into a new two level deep array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Just building on top of my previous question here:

[Rewriting a JSON string - grouping keys by value into a new array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896415/rewriting-a-json-string-grouping-keys-by-value-into-a-new-array)

I am wondering how do I traverse the array given and resort it so that the output comes out something like this:

```
[{
"Name": "Title 1",
"Date": "2012-12-05",
"rows": [
    {
        "Subtitle": "Subtitle 1",
        "Count1": 566,
        "Count2": 105
    },
    {
        "Subtitle": "Subtitle 2",
        "Count1": 76,
        "Count2": 15
    }
    ]
}, 
{
"Name": "Title 2",
"Date": "2012-12-06",
"rows": [
    {
        "Count1": 66,
        "Count2": 5
    }...
```

where the original json array is grouped by "Name" column, and then sorted into multi-level structure like this (parent/multiple child json structure for properly building menu in our application)?

The original json data looks like this:

```
[{
"Name": "Title 1",
"Subtitle": "Subtitle 1",
"Count1": 556,
"Count2": 5,
"Date": "2012-12-05"
}, {
"Name": "Title 1",
"Subtitle": "Subtitle 2",
"Count1": 10,
"Count2": 100,
"Date": "2012-12-05"
}, {
"Name": "Title 3",
"Subtitle": "Subtitle 3",
"Count1": 798,
"Count2": 11,
"Date": "2012-12-04"
}...
```

and obviously I am looking for a solution in PHP, as I will read in the json data, process it and spit it out reformatted.

Comment: What does the original data look like? The data in the earlier question doesn't have subtitles. And more to the point: what have you tried? You seem to be using SO as a "write this for me" service, it's supposed to be "help me fix my code".

Comment: I've updated the original question with the sample json data for this... and what have I tried? Nothing yet as I can't even fathom in my head how I'd approach this to begin with... hence the question. If I tried something and it was close but didn't work exactly the way I needed it, I would've posted that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming associative arrays and sorting output by name:

```
$output = array();

for ($data as $row) {

    if (!isset($output[$row['Name']])) {
        $output[$row['Name']] = array(
            'Name' => $row['Name'],
            'Date' => $row['Date'],
            'rows' => array()
        );
    }

    $output[$row['Name']]['rows'][] = array(
        'Subtitle' => $row['Subtitle'],
        'Count 1'  => $row['Count 1'],
        'Count 2'  => $row['Count 2'] 
    );
}
```

Comment: I was pretty close with what I had on my end... I just ended up using array_push at the very end instead to add a new child item, but was missing a piece of the puzzle from the code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {};
result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i].Name;
    if (!hash.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        var newitem = { Name: name,
                        Date: data[i].Date,
                        rows: []
                      };
        result.push(newitem);
        hash[name] = newitem;
    }
    hash[name].rows.push({ Subtitle: data[i].Subtitle,
                           Count1: data[i].Count1,
                           Count2: data[i].Count2
                         });
}
```

Comment: I'd need this in PHP, as doing it in the front-end, given the data set I'll be working with, will cause way too much overhead in the browser... but thanks for that approach/solution.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. But the algorithm is the same, just change the syntax.